# Web App Subproject

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

When the servlet container is started using xsbt-web-plugin, it adds the context for `<root dir>/target/webapp`.  I have a multiproject set up where the web app is a subproject.  How is the context added for a subproject instead of the root project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi-module sbt project where xsbt-web-plugin is added to one of the submodules, the `webapp` directory will be created under `<project>/<submodule>/target/webapp`.

An [example multi-module project](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/tree/4.0.2/src/sbt-test/container/multi-module-single-webapp) can be found in the scripted tests directory.  In this example, the project is called `multi-module-single-webapp`, and the Web submodule is called `mathsweb`, so the `webapp` directory can be found under `multi-module-single-webapp/mathsweb/target/webapp`.

To have sbt show you the full path of the `webapp` directory, you can run `show webappPrepare` at the sbt prompt:

```
sbt:root> show webappPrepare
...
[info] * (/home/james/code/multi-module-single-webapp/mathsweb/target/webapp,)
...
```

You can optionally specify the Web submodule name:

```
sbt:root> show mathsweb/webappPrepare
...
[info] * (/home/james/code/multi-module-single-webapp/mathsweb/target/webapp,)
...
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is it possible to do this with only the root project having a build.sbt?

Comment: Looks like I can:  https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Using-Plugins.html

Comment: Yes, you can configure all modules/projects in the root project's build.sbt and plugins.sbt: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html